# Converting one column into 7 rows in excel

Tags: excel

I have a excel file with 301 items (this may change depending on the month) in column A.
I need to convert that into 7 rows of X number of items. Then after the 7th row the pattern repeats.
So the data looks like this:

[image]

Comment: In you image, the 3rd column repeats, but the 4th and 5th do not.  Is this the desired effect?

Comment: Sorry about the picture I did not have enough room to put the entire picture on there. The data is in Column A with 301 data points. We need to have these points imputed in 7 rows starting in column D. I believe the rows will extend to column AS. New to this site not sure how to add a file.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in `D1`:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW($A1)+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*7,1))
```

Fill the formula down to `D7`.  Then fill `D1:D7` as far right as you can until you see zeros.

***UPDATE: Better Answer***

Although the above works, I realized a better (simpler) answer last night.  Same instructions as before.

```
=OFFSET($A1,(COLUMN(A1)-1)*7,0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! When I plug this formula into D1 it gives me a zero.   I will update my image so you can see.

Comment: Did you mean to put =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW($A1)+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*7,1)) ?

Answer (score 0):

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS((ROW($A1)-1)*3+COLUMN(A1),1))`

Enter the formula above into a blank cell. Copy it 2 cells to the right, then down until you start to get zeros (delete these).

In this formula, A1 points to the first item in the column you want to re-arrange. To change the number of columns, modify 3 in the formula into something else.